# Android - Error:A prblem occurred configuring project ':app'

Tags: android, android-studio, groovy, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

my laptop suddenly got switched off while code was compiling.
and the files where i had made changes got corrupted. i fixed them again and this is the error i got while compiling.

can anybody help me figuring out what this is?

> Failed to deserialize script metadata extracted using
>   org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.SubsetScriptTransformer for build
>   file '/home/viraj/TutsTry/Airfollow/app/build.gradle'

Comment: Did you try to clean?

Comment: yes i tried cleaning. still the same problem. unable to figure out what went wrong.

Comment: try removing the hidden `.gradle` folder from your project folder.  One of the files might be corrupted, and if you remove it, it will be rebuilt

Comment: deleted and cleaned.still no luck

Comment: Try `mv ~/.gradle/caches ~/.gradle/caches_orig` and try again. If that works,  remove  `caches_orig` directory. If not, move it back ;-)

Comment: Thanks @tim_yates i created new project and copied the src folder from corrupted project. :) works fine

Comment: When I add "--stacktrace --debug" to the build scrip, and I found some files in ".gradle\caches\2.10\scripts" was broken.

Answer (score 5):

Simply Solve like this

**Project -> Open Module Settings -> SDK Location -> Android NDK location:** Remove the location path and click **'OK'**

Rebuild Again

Comment: Now located at `Preferences > Appearance and Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK`

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove or add something to the `build.gradle` file that should force it to resync and update dependencies.
I had such problem after working sometime in offline mode, not exactly `Offline mode` from the gradle menu, but without internet connection

Answer (score 2):

please add newline in the end of build.gradle file

Comment: Confirming this.

Answer (score 0):

Run `gradlew` with `--debug`

Similar issue happened to me. I had a build that was interrupted by my machine crashing hard.

After combing through the output from running `gradlew` with the `--debug` option, I found the lock file that was causing gradle trouble. Sadly, I didn't think to save the example output, so I can't paste it here, but it shouldn't be too hard to find in case anyone else runs into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue, in my case my SDK path was incorrect. I fixed SDK path and it worked for me.